# Django Change File name in PDF export

Tags: python, django, pdf

I found this handy code in the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/):

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from django.http import HttpResponse

    def some_view(request):
        # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate PDF headers.
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'

        # Create the PDF object, using the response object as its "file."
        p = canvas.Canvas(response)

        # Draw things on the PDF. Here's where the PDF generation happens.
        # See the ReportLab documentation for the full list of functionality.
        p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world.")

        # Close the PDF object cleanly, and we're done.
        p.showPage()
        p.save()
        return response
```

I would like to pass a variable to the function as variable name, but cannot figure it out (though I am sure it is super easy).

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`filename="somefilename.pdf"` there is place where you can determine your filename.
You can use it as:

```
filename = 'somefilename.pdf'
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(filename)
```

Comment: @kftb Here It is editing the file name inside the code manually. Is it possible to change the name dynamically here ?

Comment: Sure, you can pass whatever you want to filename 'somefilename.pdf'. In my case, I want it to be connected to the userprofile, so I have filename = str(request.user.userprofile.course_accid) + ".pdf" for example.

Comment: @kftb Okay, glad to know that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope it might helps you:

Add one more argument named "name" to the view "some_view" and replace the filename with the argument value.

```
def hello_pdf(request, name):

# Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate PDF headers.
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.pdf'% name

temp = StringIO()

# Create the PDF object, using the StringIO object as its "file."
p = canvas.Canvas(temp)

# Draw things on the PDF. Here's where the PDF generation happens.
# See the ReportLab documentation for the full list of functionality.
p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world.")

# Close the PDF object cleanly.
p.showPage()
p.save()

# Get the value of the StringIO buffer and write it to the response.
response.write(temp.getvalue())
return response
```

Check the name argument replacing the filename in the 4th line of code. Also don't forget to update the urls.py like below:

```
 url(r'^(?P<name>\w+)/$', 'app.some_view')
```

After all pass the filename you wish to replace with url like below:

http://yourwebsite.com/name-of-file/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force viewing the PDF in browser with given filename but without automatic download, you can use "inline" instead of "attachment":

```
response["Content-Disposition"] = f'inline; filename="{file_name}"'
```

Comment: No, try it for yourself in Chrome. `f'inline; filename="{file_name}"'` and `f'attachment; filename="{file_name}"'` will not yield the same UX.

Comment: I just tried in our business application. If I disable Chrome PDF Viewer and use "inline", then "inline" will behave exactly as "attachment", since Chrome will auto-download it, and let you do what you want with the downloaded file. Hence, indeed "inline" may be modified by the browser settings. In fact "inline" without filename is the default. The problem of "attachment" is that it always fills your download folder, and you must manually clean it. With "inline" and filename, you can save the document with the correct filename, but can consult many documents without cleaning every time.