# How can I set the filename for base64 pdf in iframe?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have a report PDF in base64, I want to show the file embedded in the HTML page. To do this I use the iFrame and works, but the problem is that I can't set the name of the PDF so that when downloaded it will be saved with the name assigned.

Can I set the filename?, if yes, how can I do it?

this is my code:

```js
var iFrameBlock = $("<iframe>").attr({
      "src": base64file_encode,
      "width": "100%",
      "height": "100%",
      "frameborder": "0"
});

$("#previewPDF").html(iFrameBlock);
```

The result:
[Preview of PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL3ss.png)

And when I try download the file, the name to be saved is "download.pdf"
[Save dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YotAs.png)

I tried differents ways, but do not work either:

1. Adding attribute ***download="filename.pdf"***

   ```js
      
      var iFrameBlock = $("<iframe>").attr({
         "src": base64file_encode,
         "width": "100%",
         "height": "100%",
         "frameborder": "0",
         "download": "filename.pdf"
      });
   ```
2. I tried to change the value inside the iframe, but I could find the correct attribute and the Chrome denied the action.

   ```js
      
      var iframe = $("iframe")[0];
      var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
      //here I suppose is the label of the filename
      $(iframeDocument).find("viewer-pdf-toolbar");
   ```

However, I want prevent use any other library.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Maybe see this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73898949/5796086

Answer (score -2):

The `iframe` element can't do that, but as an alternative you can add anchor tag.

```
var iFrameBlock = $("<iframe>").attr({
    "id": "iframe",
    "src": base64file_encode,
    "width": "100%",
    "height": "100%",
    "frameborder": "0"
});
var aTag = $("<a>Dwonload</a>").attr({
    "href": base64file_encode,
    "download": "yourName.pdf"
});
$("#previewPDF").html(iFrameBlock);
aTag.insertAfter($("#iframe"));
```