# Set default filename when downloading a PDF open with Chrome PDF viewer

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf, iframe, jspdf

My angular app has an iframe that renders a PDF:

```
<iframe ng-src="{{PCtrl.docSrc}}" type="application/pdf" ...></iframe>
```

docSrc is generated as a BASE64 encoded string, something like:

```
"data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKMyA..."
```

Chrome renders the embedded PDF just fine. The PDF can be downloaded clicking on download, and the user will be presented with a "save as" dialog. The default filename given by the Chrome PDF viewer is "download.pdf", how do I change it?

Comment: Already [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061354/set-the-default-save-as-name-for-a-an-embed-or-iframe-that-uses-a-blob/44061918#44061918). No real solution, except running your own pdf viewer.

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40507464/how-can-i-set-the-filename-for-base64-pdf-in-iframe

Comment: Thanks Kaido/Michael but there is nothing in those answers that help me to rename the file passed to the Google Pdf viewer, so it can be saved with a custom name when downloaded.

Comment: Hi @Miki I currently just ran into the same issue, did you find a way to set the name? It seems by default Chrome will set to download.pdf, but in Edge it sets to a random string

Comment: @ThuanTran no, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

```js
window.onload = () => {
  let blob = new Blob(["file"], {
    type: "text/plain"
  });
  let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  let a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = url;
  a.download = "file.txt";
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  console.log(url);
  a.click();
}
```

may be this will help you

Comment: Thanks Selva. You are attaching the file to an `<a>` element, which supports the **download** attribute. Unfortunately, an _iframe_ does not support it.